# About Android compiler

Tags: java, android

When building an Android application, which compiler does ADT use?  ECJ or Javac?  Does it provide the compiler for Dalvik machine?

Comment: This question is incomprehensible.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which kind of compiler ADT exactly use ECJ or Javac?

Android requires the Java SDK (including OpenJDK) and uses `javac` from there.

> does it provide the compiler for Davilk machine?

The Android SDK provides a cross-compiler between `javac`-generated bytecode and Dalvik bytecode.